# source of "logistic growth"?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, differential-equations

I've been trying to find the source of the name of the DE modelling population growth known as logistic growth, for some time: why "Logistic" ? So far all my attempts to research it have hit dead ends - very curious if any math/ French language buffs have any idea.

The only suggestion I have found is a rather tenuous tie to the French "logis" (for dwelling/home) but this doesn't seem very plausible given it doesn't have a corresponding adjectival form.

Comment: It seems not to be known why Verhulst, who introduced the term, used it. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357918/why-is-logistic-equation-called-logistic

Comment: thank you for the link. Disappointing though: it's so unsatisfying not to know what his logic was!

Comment: Read Shulman ([1998](//doi.org/10.1080/10511979808965879); [pdf](//www.researchgate.net/publication/233238354_Math-alive_using_original_sources_to_teach_mathematics_in_social_context)) for a breathless account of what finding Verhulst’s paper felt like, before digitization.

Answer (score 7):

According to some on-line resources for historical French lexicon, around 1770 [see : [Fortunato Bartolomeo De Felice](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortunato_Bartolomeo_De_Felice), vol.26 of: [Encyclopédie ou Dictionnaire universel raisonné des connoissances humaines](https://books.google.it/books?id=f04VAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA513&lpg=PA513) (1773)] :

> [Adjectivement] **Logarithmes logistiques**, logarithmes dans lesquels zéro est le logarithme correspondant au nombre 3600. Ces logarithmes sont commodes pour les calculs astronomiques [see [Jérôme Lalande](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%A9r%C3%B4me_Lalande), *Astronomie*, par M. de La Lande, Tome premier (1764, enlarged edition, 4 vols, 1771–1781), **Table LXXVII**, [page 89](https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&id=otEN5iMke6kC&q=logistique) ].

This, it seems, must be the source of the name: *courbe logistique* [logistic curve] used by [Pierre François Verhulst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Fran%C3%A7ois_Verhulst) in his 1845 work: "*Recherches mathématiques sur la loi d'accroissement de la population*".

See  [page 8](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=PPN129323640_0018|LOG_0009&physid=PHYS_0021).

Comment: "Logistic logarithms, logarithms in which zero is the logarithm corresponding to the number 3600. These logarithms are convenient for astronomical calculations".

Answer (score 3):

As Mauro states, the term *[logistic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logistic)* is due to the Belgian mathematician [Pierre François Verhulst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Fran%C3%A7ois_Verhulst), who invented the [logistic growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_growth) model, and named it *logistic* (French: *[logistique](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logistique)*) in his 1845 "Recherches mathématiques sur la loi d'accroissement de la population", [p. 8](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN129323640_0018?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B21%5D,%22view%22:%22info%22%7D):

> Nous donnerons le nom de *logistique* à la courbe
>
> > We will give the name *logistic* to the curve

He does not explain why he uses this term, but it is presumably by analogy with *arithmetic*, *geometric*, and in contrast to *logarithmic*, as in [figure](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN129323640_0018?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B54%5D,%22panX%22:0.487,%22panY%22:0.616,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.592%7D) below (from the original paper).

The French term *logistique* is from Ancient Greek λογιστικός (logistikós, “practiced in arithmetic; rational”), from λογίζομαι (logízomai, “I reason, I calculate”), from λόγος (lógos, “reason, computation”), whence English *logos*, *logic*, *logarithm*, etc. In Ancient Greek mathematics, *logistikós* was a division of mathematics: practical computation and accounting, in contrast to ἀριθμητική (arithmētikḗ), the theoretical or philosophical study of numbers. Confusingly, today we call practical computation *arithmetic*, and don't use *logistic* to refer to computation.

Verhulst first discusses the [arithmetic growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_growth) and [geometric growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_growth) models, referring to arithmetic *progression* and geometric *progression*, and calling the geometric growth curve a *logarithmic* curve (confusingly, the modern term is instead *exponential* curve, which is the inverse), then follows with his new model of "logistic" growth, which is presumably named by analogy, after a traditional division of mathematics, and in contrast to the logarithmic curve. The term *logarithm* is itself derived as *log-arithm*, from Ancient Greek λόγος (*lógos*) and ἀριθμός (*arithmós*), the sources respectively of *logistic* and *arithmetic*.

There is no connection with *logis* (lodging), though that is the source of the term *[logistics](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logistics)* (1830).

[image: Graph of logistic curve, contrasted with logarithmic curve, Verhulst 1845]

- Cross-posted at *Cross Validated:* [Why is the logistic distribution called “logistic”?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/374825/83275)
- Cross-posted at *Mathematics:* [Why is logistic equation called “logistic”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2975512/256893)

Comment: ([Belgian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Belgian_mathematicians) mathematician.) I agree that the arithmetic / geometric / logistic split sounds like our best guess as to what he may have been thinking — however self-aggrandizing! Also while at it, [stats.se](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192948/why-is-the-logistic-distribution-called-logistic) has yet another iteration of the question.

Comment: Thanks @FrancoisZiegler, fixed, and linked! There's also a clear logarithmic/logistic contrast, which I hadn't mentioned; noted.

Answer (score 2):

Side remark: Huygens had previously used that name for the graph of logarithm, in *Discours de la cause de la pesanteur* ([1690](//www.dbnl.org/tekst/huyg003oeuv21_01/huyg003oeuv21_01_0084.php#963T), p. 169):

> ... there was a curved line, which I had examined [much before](//dbnl.nl/tekst/huyg003oeuv14_01/huyg003oeuv14_01_0049.php), which was of great use in this research. One can call it ***Logarithmic*** or ***Logistic***, for I don’t see that anyone has yet named it, although others also considered it before.

Latin version with elaboration by G. Grandi in *Opera reliqua* ([1728](//doi.org/10.3931/e-rara-4462), pp. 130, 135, 149–288). Same in the *Cyclopaedia* ([1728](https://archive.org/details/Cyclopediachambers-Volume2/page/n114): Logistic Line, Logistic Spiral, Logistical Arithmetic) and in Roger Boscovich, *De cycloide et logistica* ([1745](//doi.org/10.3931/e-rara-3504), p. 80) and also *Theoria philosophiae naturalis* ([1763](//books.google.com/books?id=RH5jw_7UOT4C&pg=PA261&dq=logistic+curve), pp. 260–261). Lalande, already quoted by Mauro Allegranza, confirms in his Vol. 3 ([1771](//archive.org/details/astronomie03lala/page/750), nº 3915):

> Logistics is the name one used to call algebra; later one gave it to the logarithmic curve; today it is devoted to this little kind of logarithms [“[logistic logarithms](https://archive.org/details/lelaroussepourto02laro/page/58)”]; perhaps this word comes from *λογὶζομαι Colligo*, because algebra packs many things in few characters.

As to “algebra”, Cajori says ([1896](https://archive.org/details/mathehistory00cajorich/page/26), p. 26): “Greek mathematicians were in the habit of discriminating between the science of numbers and the art of computation. The former they called *arithmetica*, the latter *logistica*.” Later Vieta used logistica *numerosa* and *speciosa*, and maybe not coincidentally, a Belgian biography of Stevin had recapped, shortly before Verhulst’s paper (Goethals [1841](https://books.google.com/books?id=OAhiAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA13&dq=logistique), p. 13):

> ***Logistica numerosa*** was properly arithmetic; ***logistica speciosa*** was algebra, which since Vieta, contemporary of Stevin, split into two branches (...). The ***logistic*** due to Monk Barlaam, who flourished in 1350, was originally the arithmetic of sexagesimal fractions, more curious than useful. This word was long kept; and by the end of Stevin’s career, it was still used by the mathematician Beyer who published, in 1619, a treatise on ***decimal and sexagesimal logistic***.

So the word had been through quite a few different meanings when Verhulst ([1845](https://books.google.com/books?id=b0JUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA8&dq=logistique)) co-opted it out of obsolescence again — with no apparent explanation. Whence understandable confusions, such as Wikipedia [linking Boscovich to the wrong graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Joseph_Boscovich#Middle_years).